# Stack trace exception while saving object to database Django SQLITE3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I had a really tough time to get fix this issue please help if you know this.
I have a project on django, It contain model with two fields, one is of type foreign key and other one is jsonfield. When it goes to save object in database, 
it doesn't get saved instead it throw exception. I don't know what's the issue is. But issue is only specific to sqlite3 database. it is working fine with other databases. I am pasting stack trace and code. it throws exception on this line
student_record_obj.save()

Stack trace:

```
Internal Server Error: /tableapp/postdata/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jdidi\Documents\Fresh\calendardjangoapp\tableapp\views.py", line 89, in posting_data
    student_record_obj.save()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 104, in execute
    sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 136, in last_executed_query
    params = self._quote_params_for_last_executed_query(params)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 125, in _quote_params_for_last_executed_query
    return cursor.execute(sql, params).fetchone()
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[10/Jul/2018 23:01:32] "POST /tableapp/postdata/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18778
```

VIEWS.PY:

```
def posting_data(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        response_ls = json.loads(request.POST.get('data', []))
        final_ls = []
        for dic in response_ls:
            if dic and "csrfmiddlewaretoken" not in dic:
                final_ls.append(dic)

        try:
            student_record_obj = StudentRecords.objects.get(user=request.user)
            student_record_obj.data = final_ls
        except StudentRecords.DoesNotExist:
            attrs = {'user':request.user , 'data': final_ls}
            student_record_obj = StudentRecords(**attrs)

        student_record_obj.save()
    return redirect('/tableapp/index')
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to save a list object to a model field - that will not work because a list is not a data type that you can throw at a database. What field type are you using for `StudentRecords.data`?

Comment: it is jsonfield

Comment: SQLite doesn't support JSONField. You have to use Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code above, `final_ls` variable is a list which is not insertable to database as such.
Dummp it as json string and then save it:

```
import json
.
.
final_ls = json.dumps(context)
attrs = {'user':request.user , 'data': final_ls}
student_record_obj = StudentRecords(**attrs)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and final_ls is list which contains dict

Comment: yes, I misread, a list. I understand it produces the same error? Can you provide definition of the model StudentRecords?